# AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'lower'

Tags: python, pandas

Here's my code

`actual = actual.apply(lambda x:x.lower())`

Here's the error

```
/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in apply(self, func, axis, raw, result_type, args, **kwds)
   7550             kwds=kwds,
   7551         )
-> 7552         return op.get_result()
   7553 
   7554     def applymap(self, func) -> "DataFrame":

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in get_result(self)
    183             return self.apply_raw()
    184 
--> 185         return self.apply_standard()
    186 
    187     def apply_empty_result(self):

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in apply_standard(self)
    274 
    275     def apply_standard(self):
--> 276         results, res_index = self.apply_series_generator()
    277 
    278         # wrap results

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in apply_series_generator(self)
    303                 for i, v in enumerate(series_gen):
    304                     # ignore SettingWithCopy here in case the user mutates
--> 305                     results[i] = self.f(v)
    306                     if isinstance(results[i], ABCSeries):
    307                         # If we have a view on v, we need to make a copy because

<ipython-input-94-4585873426da> in <lambda>(x)
      1 import pandas as pd
      2 actual = pd.read_csv("Data Rumah Sakit.csv", error_bad_lines=False, sep = ";")
----> 3 actual = actual.apply(lambda x:x.lower())
      4 actual["Rumah Sakit"] = actual["Rumah Sakit"].str.replace('[^\w\s]','')

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5139             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
   5140                 return self[name]
-> 5141             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5142 
   5143     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value) -> None:

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.str.lower` instead of just `.lower`:

```
actual = actual.apply(lambda x:x.str.lower())
```